# Pricing of constant leverage certificates

Tags: derivatives, pricing, valuation, leverage

I am trying to value the open-ended constant leverage certificates like [Bull DAX 20x](https://certificates.vontobel.com/SE/EN/Product/DE000VV3WRR3?ReturnUrl=%2fSE%2fEN%2fProducts%2fProduct_search%2fbull-and-bear-matrix&FromPath=Produkter--Produkts%c3%b6k--Bull+%26+Bear+Matris--). As the certificates are reset daily with the movements of the underlying asset, how could they be modeled for pricing?

The paper "[The Price-setting Behavior of Banks:
An Analysis of Open-end Leverage Certificates on the German Market](https://www.efmaefm.org/0efmameetings/efma%20annual%20meetings/2007-Austria/papers/0475.pdf)" by Entrop et al (2007) argues that the price would only depend on the spot price of the underlying, but neither the volatility nor the knock-out barrier, on page 5.

How else could it be done?

Comment: Why don't you wish to use the model described in that paper?

Comment: I might be wrong here, but if I understand the paper correct, and specifically the equation in (5), the pricing used by the banks issuing the instrument is not applicable to the investor for reasons outlined in the paper, e.g. money market access and interest rates used (it says something about not being able to create such portfolio for the investor to replicate the instrument). So my question was if there was any "other" pricing approach that would be more applicable for the investor side. which might not yield the same answer as the equation in (5).

Comment: I also though the underlying movements would have had to be represented by some Brownian motion, or similar. But I'm just really trying to understand, even though I'm not a quant :)

Comment: It might help if you update your question to include these points. However, pls note that this site is mainly for people who know quantitative financial methods to a significant extent.